# Getting the max value from where polygons intersect in MapInfo

Tags: polygon, mapinfo, 2d

I am trying to do an intersect query on two polygon layers in MapInfo. One is a buildings layer and the other are 2d mesh triangles. I want to get the max depth from any of the triangles that intersect the buildings layer. As multiple meshes intersect a single building polygon I end up with multiple entries of that building polygon in the background table, with each duplicate entry having a different depth corresponding to which triangle it intersects with.

Is there a way of automating the process so that I can have one buildings layer with the max depth for that building corresponding to the triangle (2d mesh) with the max depth?

Comment: Do you want to do this via a query and see the result in a query or do you want to update your buildings with the max depth value from the triangles?

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. Add a column to your buildings table called MaxDepth (or whatever you want to call it) of the correct type, I assume Float. Then use Table > Update Column and use the below in the 'Update Column' dialog.

- Table to update: Buildings
- Column to update: MaxDepth
- Get Value from Table: MeshTriangles
- Click 'Join...' button and select 'Where object Intersects object...'
- Calculate: Max
- of: MaxDepth (or whatever the depth column is called in the mesh table)

You should now have the maximum depth from any of the intersecting triangles assigned to each building.